# Navigation title not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to make it so the title of the navigation controller is the username of the person currently signed in. I have tried the code below with no success.

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()!
self.navigationController!.navigationItem.title = user
```

and I have also tried

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()! as? String
self.navigationItem.title = user
```

I have tried multiple variations to force unwrap the username and the title but it is not working. I get the following error in most cases.

> Cannot assign a value of type 'PFUser' to a value of type 'String?'

Can anybody offer some assistance with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very silly question. But still here is the answer!

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
self.navigationItem.title = user
```

Comment: I am new to programming so I didn't think so; that being said, I think that was a little unnecessary but thanks for your answer.

Comment: @TrentonTyler no issue! But u should search before asking here.

Comment: I will make sure to do that next time! Thank you for your answer and input.

Answer (score 2):

`PFUser.currentUser` returns `Self?` so it returns type `PFUser`. You cannot cast `PFUser` to `String` what do you expect to get with this cast?

If you need the name then `PFUser` has default property `username` so you can do it like `PFUser.currentUser()!.username`